# Do I need a 'vbmeta' partition to install GSI?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, partitions, gsi

Following the official GSI installation instructions from [Google](https://source.android.com/setup/build/gsi#flashing-gsis), they say to run `fastboot --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img`.

When I run that, I get the following message:

```
Rewriting vbmeta struct at offset: 0
Sending 'vbmeta' (4 KB)                            OKAY [  0.010s]
Writing 'vbmeta'                                   FAILED (remote: 'This partition doesn't exist')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Does this mean dm-verity is not in use, and I can ignore this message? Do I need to make a partition? How do I do that?

Right now the GSI image is not booting for me.

I am flashing onto the Blackview BV5500 Pro, if it matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Verified Boot and generation of vbmeta image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image)

Comment: MT6739 doesn't have vbmeta partition, the ususal way for disabing avb/dm-verity is patch the boot.img with Magisk Manager. but as you stated you want GSI just flash ROM from TWRP, i don't think that partition is required

Comment: (1) @alecxs No, that's about generating a vbmeta image. I have one already, it's included in the GSI download. (2) I'm not using TWRP, I'm using fastboot. (3) Do you have a link showing that MT6739 doesn't use a vbmeta partition? Why do you say that?

Comment: you can check from fastboot getvar all

Comment: the linked question is linked for reference

Comment: have checked TWRP recovery.fstab - it has vbmeta entry (but commented out). find a stock ROM and check scatter file maybe you can find some with vbmeta partition layout - but i recommend to try Magisk first