# Redmi note 9 brick

Tags: xiaomi, redmi

i tried to install unofficial twrp for redmi note 9. But ended up bricking my phone.
-The pc can recognise phone(there is windows sound, every 10 seconds)
-Phone is not showing anything
-MiFlashTool v1/v2 cannot see my phone, i used v2 to turn into fastboot but later couldnt reinstall global rom.
I just need to get into fastboot so I will install official rom, but I need to turn fastboot from computer

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118108/discussion-on-question-by-tony-rosey-redmi-note-9-brick).

Answer (score 0):

According to [xda-developers.com](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/redmi-note-9-twrp-recovery.4120935/post-84125831) the Unofficial TWRP works only for Redmi Note 9 ([merlin](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/merlin)) without NFC support. If your device is the NFC version you can not use this TWRP.

Furthermore it is necessary to disable [AVB](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md) before doing any modifications. The flashing instructions are incomplete. Before flashing `magisk_patched.img` or `twrp.img` make sure to flash "empty" [vbmeta](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image) images

```
fastboot flash --disable-verity --disable-verification vbmeta vbmeta.img
fastboot flash --disable-verity --disable-verification vbmeta_system vbmeta_system.img
fastboot flash --disable-verity --disable-verification vbmeta_vendor vbmeta_vendor.img
```

---

fastboot is relatively safe for flashing, however unlocked bootloader is required. therefore when flashing in *fastboot mode* do **not** flash with flash_all_lock.bat, do not try to re-lock bootloader.

---

when flashing in [SP Flash tool](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool) observe the golden rules:

- **never** use any **scatter file** that does not match your current partition layout/device/ROM
  the file name MT6769_Android_scatter.txt is no guarantee. even the Redmi Note 9 MT6769V/CZ comes in two different versions 128/64GB.
  `fastboot getvar all` may give some partition related information.
  [WwR MTK v2.51](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices) is the safest way to **create** own scatter file
- always **un**-tick preloader checkbox
  we do not want to flash preloader as this is the most imporant area in EMMC_BOOT responsible for receiving flashing instructions. if the preloader is broken, the only way to recover dead phone is from [Engineering mode](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-11802.html) via KCOLO test point
- flash in ***"Download only"*** mode only
  other modes will erase your emmc which destroys [secure boot](https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/da-flash-da-files-for-flashing-to-merlin-using-flash-tool-xiaomi-redmi-note-9-xiaomi-redmi-10x-4g.4209765