# How to install Team Win Recovery Project and Root Xiaomi Redmi Note 9

Tags: rooting, twrp, xiaomi, redmi

I need a tutorial on how to install TWRP and root my phone because I only found tutorials online for the PRO version
and as I was told I have to be very specific about my phone when installing anything root related including twrp
also can any of you recommend which root to use

Comment: root your phone with [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#downloads) (no TWRP required) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232584

Comment: how do I reply to comments? anyways @alecxs I *WANT* TWRP

Comment: @alecxs wait a sec, how do I find out if my note 9 is 4g? mobile data says 4g so is it 4g?
oh nvm 4g looks entirely different from the normal note 9

Comment: my model is exactly that but with SG at the end instead of SS which bascially means i have the upper hand (with NFC) over the SS model

Comment: after reading the whole thread again i am not sure, some people say it is **not** working for *merlin*, so maybe it works for *merlinnfc* https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4120935&page=2