# Bootloader is unlocked, fastboot returns ''FAILED (Remote: Verify state locked)

Tags: adb, root-access, fastboot, magisk

I am trying to root my Vivo V11 with Android 10. The bootloader is unlocked. It says so in the dev settings, and I have to go through the warning prompt every time I reboot my device. When I run the fastboot command to flash the patched_boot.img file, it returns:

```
C:\Program Files\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot getvar unlocked
unlocked: yes
finished. total time: 0.002s

C:\Program Files\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash boot patched_boot.img
target reported max download size of 134217728 bytes
sending 'boot' (38579 KB)...
OKAY [  1.269s]
writing 'boot'...
FAILED (remote: Verify state locked)
finished. total time: 1.276s
```

[image: error]

Things I've tried to troubleshoot:

Running cmd as Administrator (im using win10)
Confirmed OEM unlocking is turned on in the dev settings (it is, it says "bootloader is already unlocked"
Confirmed USB debugging is on
Disabled "Verify apps over USB" and "Verify bytecode of debuggable
apps" in the dev settings.
Confirmed file transfer is enabled from my PC and my Phone (it is, I can transfer files back and forth between them)
Tried a different USB cable

[EDIT]

```
PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> .\adb devices
List of devices attached
ZDIBLVIRY5DIJBEI        device

PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> .\adb reboot-bootloader
PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> .\fastboot devices
ZDIBLVIRY5DIJBEI        fastboot
PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> .\fastboot flash boot patched_boot.img
Sending 'boot' (38579 KB)                          OKAY [  1.272s]
Writing 'boot'                                     FAILED (remote: 'Verify state locked')
fastboot: error: Command failed
PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> .\fastboot flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
Sending 'vbmeta' (4 KB)                            OKAY [  0.009s]
Writing 'vbmeta'                                   FAILED (remote: 'Verify state locked')
fastboot: error: Command failed
PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> .\fastboot --disable-verity flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
Rewriting vbmeta struct at offset: 0
Sending 'vbmeta' (4 KB)                            OKAY [  0.010s]
Writing 'vbmeta'                                   FAILED (remote: 'Verify state locked')
fastboot: error: Command failed
PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> .\fastboot --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.i
mg
Rewriting vbmeta struct at offset: 0
Sending 'vbmeta' (4 KB)                            OKAY [  0.009s]
Writing 'vbmeta'                                   FAILED (remote: 'Verify state locked')
fastboot: error: Command failed
PS C:\Users\Himanshus\Downloads\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Verified Boot and generation of vbmeta image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image)

Comment: @alecxs I tried flashing a empty vbmeta.img but while flashing it the result is still same. While writing 'vbmeta' it says failed verify state locked

Comment: use official [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) and fastboot with proper flags

Comment: @alecxs i have edited the post for results it still can't verify

Comment: try `fastboot flash --disable-verity --disable-verification vbmeta vbmeta.img` and don't use Powershell btw, run *C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe* as Administrator

Comment: @alecxs still same error. Does it has something to do with device. I have Vivo V11 with android 10

Comment: readback *boot + vbmeta* from SP Flash Tool. open the dumped files with hex editor and double check the dumps are identical with stock ROM (to confirm the scatter file fits your phone) - then - and only then - flash *vbmeta_disabled.img* from SP Flash Tool. always make sure to flash in ***"Download only"*** mode only. always **un**check preloader. try to boot. finally patch the dumped boot with [magisk manager](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#downloads) and flash *magisk_patched.img*