# TWRP seems to be corrupt or not working for Infinix X5515F

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, infinix

I was trying to install TWRP recovery to my Infinix X5515F (Smart 2). I followed these steps:

- enabled OEM unlock and USB debugging
- connected to a computer
- logged into adb and sent `adb reboot bootloader`
- send `fastboot erase recovery`
- flashed [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ofhro5lFVyGWudbIJ1Kza01AbsO3m_mh/view?usp=drivesdk) file using `fastboot flash recovery <filename.img>`
- tried to boot directly from the image using `fastboot boot <filename.img>` (after a while without any response, it performed a normal boot to the system, not to recovery)

Then I tried to reboot to recovery by these methods:

- pressing and holding the Volume Up and Power buttons until the Infinix boot logo appears (after releasing all the buttons it shut down without showing anything, booted again, and performed a normal boot)
- send `adb reboot recovery` (it boots to system recovery, not to TWRP)

What is the problem? Is this image corrupt or not right? If it is, can you provide any image for X5515F (not for X5515)?

Comment: what was the output of *'fastboot flash recovery <filename.img>'* did it flash successfully?

Comment: yes it did.and boot command too

Comment: try PitchBlack Recovery for [X5515](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eRyZBUO1Dbzd1Pn0tP4L4wgZwU59Cpb3)

Comment: no i wanted to install a custom rom.

Comment: will this recovery work for **X5515F**

Comment: can you provide a vmbeta image

Comment: if you refer to 'empty' vbmeta you can generate one yourself with python (or try this [trick](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-unofficial-twrp-3-4-0-for-galaxy-s10-exynos-g970f-g973f-g975f-g977b.3924856/post-81607905)) [Android Verified Boot and generation of vbmeta image](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219968)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need vbmeta for this device since it is android 8. I searched online and it seems it has mediatek processor. Its been two years now and no one seems to answer here. Please double check if the bootloader is unlocked, this is required for installing custom roms and rooting devices...

Enter the `fastboot oem device-info` command and run it. It should list some device data, including the bootloader information.
Look for `Device Unlocked` from the info.
If it says `true` next to it, it means that your device is unlocked. If it says `false`, it means that that it’s still locked.

Once you really confirmed that it was unlocked then you can go and [try porting twrp to your stock rom `recovery.img`](https://www.hovatek.com/forum/thread-21839.html). Proceed at your own risk. Please double check the model of the stock rom since it may confuse you and you will end up bricking your phone

You should only tweak the recovery partition of this phone don't touch any other things. If it happens that the device is not opening after flashing wrong `recovery.img`. You can try [mtkclient](https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient) and use the command `python mtk e recovery`