# Do anybody know how to install twrp in Infinix Smart 2 X5515F

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, fastboot

I've been trying to install custom ROM on my device.So first I went to install TWRP. My device is Infinix Smart 2 X5515F. I followed the steps from [this](https://romprovider.com/infinix-smart-2-x5515-support/) website. I'vd downloaded the TWRP file for my device and tried to flash the file from fastboot mode, using the commands given on the site. But each time I tries to boot into recovery by `fastboot boot twrp.img` it does nothing. So I tried to get into recovery mode manually. I first rebooted the device using `fastboot reboot` and then shut down the device. Then I pressed power and volume up buttons. It took me to a window with a text of(no commands). I pressed volume up and power button once again and it took me to systems default recovery. The default one was not replaced by TWRP. Also each time I do the procedures it factory resets my device. Do anybody know any solution to this??

Comment: Have you unlocked the bootloader? Or otherwise, which step from the link are you stuck on?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Because each time I reboot the phone it shows message like your phone is unlocked and can't be trusted.

Comment: which command should i use to unlock bootloader? Isn't it `fastboot flashing unlock`

Comment: @AndrewT. first of all the site said me to unlock OEM by `fastboot oem unlock`. The command unfortunately wasn't understood by the device. So I went to the next step. I flashed the file and ready to boot into recovery by using the command `fastboot boot recovery.img` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You have to unlock the bootloader first before being able to flash custom recovery. On some sites, I read that you have to enable "OEM Unlock" from the Developer Options first before calling `fastboot oem unlock` or `fastboot flashing unlock`. However, not having the device in hand, I can't tell if the articles are correct or just clickbait.

Comment: Yes. The OEM unlock in developer options seems to be enabled by default. But the switch is disabled(The switch is on and disabled from toggling in off). I ran these commands only after that.

Comment: @alecxs It just leads me to a blank screen and nothing else. After waiting some time it just reboots into the system.

Comment: This can have following reasons 1) wrong twrp file *or* 2) flashing unsuccessful *or* 3) you did not enter recovery mode right after flashing, instead booted normally in between which caused *recovery-from-boot.p* to restore stock recovery

Comment: I checked it. The default recovery is still there. I can boot into it. The twrp is not loaded. I don't think flashing was unsuccessful because it returned me success and finish. I'm not sure about twrp file. But flashing has to wipe the existing recovery right. But why is it still there.

Comment: I've found a recovery log in which it tries to start TWRP 3.2.3 but seems to be failed. I will update my post with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TWRP seems to be currupt or not working for Infinix X5515F](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233038/twrp-seems-to-be-currupt-or-not-working-for-infinix-x5515f)