# Minimum requirements for TWRP

Tags: twrp, google-pixel-4a

I am trying to figure out why some devices like mine (Pixel 4a, Android 11 ) don't have a TWRP. It seems to be a fairly popular device, so I am presuming lack of developer support isn't a reason.

Some pointers I could find :

- Lack of space on the RAM disk? [Thread TWRP on the P4a?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/twrp-on-the-p4a.4147505/)
- Thanks to alecxs who pointed out [Test build for Android 10](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/twrp-3-4-0-0-for-sunfish-testing.4179101/page-5), which again speculates on reasons (surprisingly, no one confirmed it fully works on Android 10).
- Kernel support needed? [This kernel claims to support TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kernel-05-13-2021-fsociety-tribute-for-google-pixel-4a.4258269/)

So, I am just trying to understand from a *user point of view* what the limitations are ( I do miss [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup, at times).

Reasons, anyone?

Comment: For the first point, please let me know the command to generate information if needed

Comment: minimum requirement for official TWRP is 1) some developer 2) who owns that device 3) is interested in becoming maintainer. you still can go with unofficial TWRP meanwhile https://www.getdroidtips.com/twrp-recovery-google-pixel-4a

Comment: @alecxs thanks, I am assuming 1 and 2, as I mentioned in first paragraph. I saw 3, doesn't work and couldn't find more as to why//besides, it would be nice to just boot into it to take backup and that too doesn't work//Most importantly, developer unknown, so I am kind of scared to push on this

Comment: @alecxs also point 2, barring this linked kernel, other custom kernels don't talk of it, leading me to think kernel support is also mandatory

Comment: flash sunfish_twrp201017-test5.img along with vbmeta_disabled.img

Comment: Can you please link `vbmeta_disabled.img` and the exact process please @alecxs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Verified Boot and generation of vbmeta image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image)

Comment: @alecxs thanks, will look into it but the main question remains - what are the limitations if any?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4179101

Comment: i am not quite sure but there might some conflict with magisk as recovery_ramdisk lives in boot.img. afair order is first install twrp then magisk

Comment: Thanks @alecxs, don't know how I missed that but it won't work on Android 11 (I am on it)

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work except fastboot boot is disabled on 11 (or vbmeta)