# Prevent Bypassing Android Verified Boot in custom ROM

Tags: security, custom-roms, bootloader, magisk, aosp

Installing custom rom needs unlocked bootloader. so I unlocked bootloader.

I built a custom android 12 rom with AVB enabled for system and boot partitions and flashed it.

if I Installing apk through recovery to system partition(copy to /system/app), apk will not installed. so AVB is working normally.

But if I flash [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/) in recovery, Magisk will root device.

Also if I flash a [disabled vbmeta partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image) in fastboot and then inject some apk in the system partition, the apk will be installed in the system partition normally.

So the question is

**Is there any way to provide integrity of system without using [User-settable root of trust](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot/device-state#root-of-trust) in custom roms with unlocked bootloader?**

Comment: By unlocking bootloader you disable the central system integrity feature of Android, what do you expect? A locked bootloader + root of trust + vbmeta is the way Android is designed to provide system integrity.

Comment: thanks @Robert so what is this section in [AVB Doc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/#locked-and-unlocked-mode)? why this doc says it supports unlocked state?

Comment: If I understand the linked documentation correctly in unlocked state verification is performed but the outcome is simply saved in a flag and the boot process will continue no matter if the verification fails or succeededs.

Comment: I know Magisk had issues with [FEC](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot/dm-verity#fec) on some Moto devices. ext4-dedup could be useful too